# Scrapy Selenium clicking javascript link

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, scrapy

The page I'm crawling has a  element as below.

```
<a class="a-declarative" href="javascript:void(0)" 
data-action="a-expander-toggle" 
data-a-expander-toggle='{"allowLinkDefault":true, 
"expand_prompt":"See more", "collapse_prompt":"See less"}'>

<i class="a-icon a-icon-extender-expand"></i>
<span class="a-expander-prompt">See more</span>
</a>
```

I want to be able to click on this "See more" in selenium and then parse the response. I have this in my scrapy spider.

```
seemore = response.xpath('//a[contains(@data-action,"a-expander-toggle")]')

seemore.click()
```

But when I do the seemore.click(), it errors out. If I print my xpath selector, this is what I see.

```
# Log the "see more" link 
self.log(response.xpath('//a[contains(@data-action,"a-expander-toggle")]'))

# Log output
[<Selector xpath='//a[contains(@data-action,"a-expander-toggle")]' 
data=u'<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-action'>]
```

It's probably not reading the link correctly. Is my xpath correct to select this kind of a link?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I don't really see an error. When it goes to seemore.click() it goes to my except block where I exit out. Is there a way I can print the exception?

Comment: Try this:

`except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]) 
    raise`

Comment: `except Exception, e: print e`

Comment: You are calling `.click()` from a `SelectorList` object. It should be called from a Selenium WebElement object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Valdir Stumm Junior said, I believe you need to call the click function as a webdriver element.  Probably not the most elegant example but here's some (untested) sample code you could adapt for your case..

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

...

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    self.driver.get(response.url)
    try:
        seemore = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-expander-prompt')
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # insert how you want to handle this e.g. break, log etc

    seemore.click()
```

More details on how to get a handle to selenium elements here:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: There is no URL to issue a get request on. He needs to issue a click on an element.